# How to find circumference and area of a 2D shape whose indices are given as 0 or 1 in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, 2d, path-finding

Given a 2D array of size 20x20 whose values resemble a 2D shape, for example a square or rectangle:

```
public static int[][] rectangle= {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
        
};
```

I would like to find its circumference and area in an algorithm that does the following:

1. Finds the nearest (1) point starting from the center (point[10][10]).
2. Uses the nearest (1) point as a starting point to iterate over all the remaining 1s to count the
   circumference.
3. calculates the number of zeros **enclosed** by the circumference to calculate the area

Now below is where I am currently at; the "guess" method calculates the nearest (1) point and executes the "count" method which then calculates the circumference.

```
public static void guess() {

    boolean found = false;
    
    if(!found) {
    int  y = 10;
    for(int x = 10; x <= 20; x++) { 
            if(rectangle[x][y]==1) {
                rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                found = true;
                break;
            }else if(rectangle[x][y++]==1) {
                    rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
     }
    
    
    if(!found) {
     int  y = 10;
     for(int x = 10; x >= 0; x--) { 
            if(rectangle[x][y]==1) {
                rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                found = true;
                 break;
            }else if(rectangle[x][y--]==1) {
                    rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                    found = true;
                     break;
                }
            }
     }
    
     if(!found) {
            int  x  = 10;
            for(int y = 10; y <= 20; y++) { 
                    if(rectangle[x][y]==1) {
                        rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }else if(rectangle[x][y++]==1) {
                            rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
             }
            
            if(!found) {
             int  x = 10;
             for(int y = 10; y >= 0; y--) { 
                    if(rectangle[x][y]==1) {
                        rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                        found = true;
                         break;
                    }else if(rectangle[x][y--]==1) {
                            rectangle[x][y] = 2;
                            found = true;
                             break;
                        }
                    }
             }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if(rectangle[i][j] == 2) {
                Count(i, j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

public static void Count(int x, int y) {
    
    public int circumf;

    int tx = x;
    int ty = y;
    
    for(int c = 40; c >=0; c--) {
        if((c/2)-1<0 || x>=20 || x<0 || y>=20 || y<0) break;
        
        if(rectangle[x][(int) (c/2)-1]==1 || rectangle[(int) (c/2)-1][y]==1 
                || rectangle[x++][y]==1 || rectangle[x][y++]==1
                || rectangle[x--][(int) (c/2)-1]==1 || rectangle[(int) (c/2)-1][y--]==1 || rectangle[x--][y]==1 || rectangle[x][y--]==1) {
            circumf++;
        }
        
    }
    
    x = tx;
    y = ty;
    
    for(int c = 0; c <=40; c++) {
        if((c/2)>=20 || x>=20 || x<0 || y>=20 || y<0) break;
        
        if(rectangle[x][(int) (c/2)]==1 || rectangle[(int) (c/2)][y]==1 
                || rectangle[x++][y]==1 || rectangle[x][y++]==1
                || rectangle[x--][(int) (c/2)]==1 || rectangle[(int) (c/2)] 
       [y--]==1 || rectangle[x--][y]==1 || rectangle[x][y--]==1) {
            circumf++;
        }
    
        
    }
    
    System.out.print(circumf);
```

Now, the guess method calculates the nearest point correctly, however the count method doesn't correctly counts the circumference which is close to 70 in the above example.

As for the area calculating algorithm, I still didn't quite figure it out.

The above code isn't the most brilliant or organized thing I know, but any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Trying this out in my IDE, I get this https://imgur.com/a/6py32Ac

Comment: Oh god, i haven't noticed it. i have just changed that loop and now the circumference count has increased but not accurate though. Thanks anyways! @aksappy

Comment: Done any debugging yet? What were your findings?

Comment: My approach in the count method in the last two for loops, is we check the vertical+ and vertical- side and same thing horizontally. However it seems to have duplicate 1s counted as it doesn't show the correct circumference value. @MrSmith42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you find the nearest one at index `[i][j]`. You need to check the nearest values in a cross pattern since your object is a rectangle.

For example you are in the middle one in the left edge of the rectangle:

```
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
```

You check were the 1's "continue" finding thus the edge direction. There are 2 possible outcomes either

`[x-1][y]=[x][y]=[x+1][y] or [x][y-1]=[x][y]=[x][y+1]==1`

So,you found that the edge is vertical. Continue iterating through this verical line until the condition `[x][y-1]==1` is `false`. Then do the same thing for the horizontal line.

Now for the 0's count you could store the index i,j of all the corners while you are doing the above check.If you know their positions and the size of the array is fixed you can calculate the 0's like:

`0's area = [(DL_corner_index - 1) - (UL_corner_index + 1)] x [(UR_corner_index - 1) - (UL_corner_index + 1)]`

```
int rectangle[10][10] ={
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
   {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

//calculating area of zeros with known corner coordinates
//you have stored the coordinates in variables like this
int UL_X=1,UR_X=8;
int UL_Y=1,DL_Y=8;
int area = ((UR_X-1) - UL_X)*((DL_Y-1)-UL_Y);

cout<<area; //36
}
```

Comment: Ok i get the approach for calculating the circumference, but can you please elaborate on how we can find the area? @Panagiotis Sapountzoglou

Comment: i just noticed that your columns are actually 21 not 20. Anyways, what i am trying to say is that if you know for example the location of the upper left corner that one in `[1][1]` and that of the upper right corner `[18][1]` then the side of the inner rectangle of 0's is (18-1) - 1 = 16.You do this for one vertical edge as well and the area is a*b.I hope this helped!